# bash script - generate suggestions based on user input

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, console

Is it possible to make interactive suggestions based on user input?

Example:

```
$ my_script --check-hosts prod<TAB>
    production1.company.com    production-db1.company.com
    production2.company.com
    production3.company.com
```

In different cases I should query dns records, grep files etc.
I know about `bash_completion` but is it possible to generate this list on the fly?

Comment: while setting `COMPREPLY` you can get the whole list of domain names on the fly using another custom script

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a new file here:

```
/etc/bash_completion.d/myfunction
```

Update any references to myfunction within the first and last line of the code block below. You can also update the flags variable with any auto-completed terms you would like. --help and --version are currently set.

```
_myfunction() 
{
    local cur prev flags
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    flags="--help --version"

    if [[ ${cur} == -* ]] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${flags}" -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
    fi
}
complete -F _myfunction myfunction
```

Once you have created this file, reload bash.

```
bash
```

Then, auto-completion should be working.

```
$ myfunction --
--help     --version
```